# How to set default initialization tool in Autodesk Viewer when loading a model?

Tags: autodesk-viewer, autodesk

Upon initiating the model within the viewer (utilizing viewer version 7.95), the preset tool activated by default is the orbit tool, I want to alter this to the pan tool, just exec `viewer.toolController.activateTool("pan")` when loading a model could throw an error because toolController's not avaliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT, async () => {
   viewer.toolController.activateTool("pan")
})
```

In my testing TOOLBAR_CREATED_EVENT didn't work, so we have to rely on GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT.